# Error handling in C++ - Trying to go back to a specified statement

Tags: c++, statements

I was thinking, is there any way you can use throw/try/catch without closing the program?

For example:

```
function
{
restore point:
//code goes here
try "something";
goto restore point;
}
```

Is there any method to call function and, if the condition is not verified in try statement, to go back to identifier?

Here`s my case:

```
 int Automat::Retragere()
{
    int suma;
    cout<<"\n Introduceti suma pe care doriti s-o retrageti: ";
    cin>>suma;
    if(suma > 5000){
        throw "\n Suma este mai mare decat plafonul maximal zilnic.";
    }
    else{
        if(suma > sold){
            throw "\n Suma este mai mare decat SOLDUL curent.";
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Operatiune efectuata cu succes.";
            sold = sold - suma;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

marcaj2:
//code here
    switch(optiune){
    case 1:
        Retragere();
        goto marcaj2;
    case 2:
        Depunere();
        goto marcaj2;
    case 3:
        Transfer();
        goto marcaj2;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

I`m asking if, after calling "Retragere" function, is there a posibility to go back to my identifier in case try encounters an error.

Comment: Why not simply using a try/catch from within a loop?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using goto, it's awful. Learn about proper looping.

Comment: Every part of this code is a total abuse of every language feature it uses. Don't use exceptions for non-exceptional control flow, and don't use goto for loops.

Comment: @KerrekSB Fixing one of those will fix both. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the case you present, `Automat::Retragere` should probably not throw any exceptions but just return error codes describing what was wrong, since "input too large" (larger than allowed or larger than sum on account) are not really exceptional states. Use an enum with speaking names for that instead of plain `int`. With a simple return value you are free to use ordinary control flow like a while loop for the input until the number is allowed etc.

Design interlude: That would be different if this was a routine expecting sanitized input so that these conditions indicate a program error. In fact, one should probably already at this stage separate data acquisition from business logic.

This means here that one function is responsible for obtaining the input and checking it; another function would expect valid input (no strings, but a number indicating a valid amount) and perform the actual business action like withdrawel or deposit. It's only a one-liner here but in the real world may involve establishing a connection of some sort, authentication etc.

The business function could throw when presented with an invalid number, because the data provider broke its contract.

Concerning the technical aspect of your question: The 2011 standard says in 15/3:

> A goto, break, return, or continue statement can be used to transfer
>   control out of a try block or handler.

I cannot imagine any ordinary reason to do that, but it is not illegal. (Some of the provisions surrounding `goto`, arguably even `goto` proper,  target machine generated code or similar scenarios.)

It may well be possible to handle certain exceptions locally; a saner approach (saner than `goto` directly from inside the catch block to somewhere in the function) would be to have the try/catch block in a loop. The catch block would examine the exception and either set an error code which is then checked in the loop condition, or possibly re-throw exceptions which are unknown or too severe to recover from locally.

Comment: Valuable details from Standard.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    //marcaj2:
    switch(optiune){
    case 1:
        Retragere();
        break;        // break out of the switch, i.e. will continue at while (!done)
                      // so it similar to goto marcaj2
    case 2:
        Depunere();
        break;
    case 3:
        Transfer();
        break;
    default:
        done = true;   // end the while loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Others have already commented that the exception throw is bad.

But if you really want it, I think you can do it something like:

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    try
    {
        //marcaj2:
        switch(optiune){
        case 1:
            Retragere();
            break;        // break out of the switch, i.e. will continue at while (!done)
                          // so it similar to goto marcaj2
        case 2:
            Depunere();
            break;
        case 3:
            Transfer();
            break;
        default:
            done = true;   // end the while loop
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // error handling...
    }
}
```